# C# Get String from Private void

Tags: c#, string, private, protected, void

i need to get a string from a private void
in this code in need the teamsite string

```
protected override void test
    teamsitefinal = teamsite
}
```

from this code

```
private void test2 {
   string teamsite = "test"
}
```

i can't change the private void or protected override void

Comment: did my solution meet your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the string into a private field of the class.

```
class MyClass : SomeBaseClass
{
   string teamsite;
   protected override void test ()
   {
      string teamsitefinal = teamsite;
   }
   private void test2 ()
   {
      teamsite = "test";
   }
}
```

Comment: did you test this code? It does not work.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you tried to do here.

Comment: @Senthess, me neither. ;-)  this better?

Comment: "get or set accessor expected" - seriously test your code!

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback, (it was my first time on this site) this was what i needed to have done, when i asked this question i just started programming and didn't understand the rules for scoping.

Answer (score 2):

So as I understand it `test2` is a method which declares a variable which you need to access from within another method `test` - if this is the case then unless `test2` either passes the value of this string to another function, or in some way returns the value of this string this simply isn't possible.

The string `teamsite` is only in scope (that is, it only *exists*) during the execution of that method.

Answer (score 0):

You can still overload the function though? If so then pass the string as a ref parameter and the function then fills it.